# Ubuntu 19.10 Takes forever to boot

Tags: boot

This started happening yesterday for no reason but whenever I try to boot up Ubuntu, it takes forever. Usually booting it up through the recovery mode fixes it but then the OS can't detect my monitor.
I can't access the internet neither but I asked about that in a different question.

I have a dual boot setup (Win10 Pro and Ubuntu) 
Win10: 1.5tb
Ubuntu: 0.5tb

32gb DDR3 RAM
8gb Radeon RX590

Comment: If you run `systemd-analyze blame` you can see why it's taking so long.

Comment: How do I do that if I can't boot it up normally

Comment: Also, by forever, I mean it never goes past the logo screen. It's been on the same logo screen since 12 hours ago.

Comment: Just did the command in recovery model's root option https://imgur.com/a/vbs98qG

Comment: ah, I thought that you meant that it just takes a long time, not literally forever.